# Need help moving data from one partiton to another NTFS

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

Recently my hard drive on which I had Windows installed got damaged. The other one that I stored my data works fine, thus I want to move data from one of the partitions to another partition so that I can install Windows on it. So far I have been able to get read and write permissions in the partition using `sudo chmod ugo+wx /dev/sda1` but I cannot move or create directory in the partition. The partition is NTFS

Below is the error

[image: Error]

Comment: Open terminal. Run `sudo parted -l`. Which partition is your data on? Which partition do you want to move it to?

Comment: It's on `dev/sda1` and i want to move it to `dev/sda6`

Comment: There are different methods to use. First, is all your data in one folder or in several folders. Are there other folders/files on sda1, and if so how do you distinguish your data files from these other ones? Which partition is Windows in?

Comment: what command `mount` says

Comment: My data is in several folders and there are many other folders that i don't want except a few.. My windows was in other hard drive which got corrupted so there is no windows in this one..

Answer (score 0):

Using Terminal (Use this when you are currently logged in Ubuntu):

Quickly open the terminal or press CtrlAltT

First you need to find out the partition’s name which you want to access, run the following command:

`sudo fdisk -l` 
Then run this command in your terminal, to access your drive in read/write mode.

`mount -t ntfs-3g -o rw /dev/sda1 /media/<YOUR-Partition-name>`
OR Run this command (if the previous didn’t work)

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/<YOUR-Partition-name>`
'The second one worked for me'